# React ModalUnstyled not closing when clicking outside of modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I feel like this code used to work fine before, not all of a sudden when clicking outside of the modal the modal does not close.

```
const StyledModal = styled(ModalUnstyled)`
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1300;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Backdrop = styled('div')`
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
`;

function style(props) {
return {
    width: 250,
    bgcolor: '#ffffff',
    color: '#000000',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    p: 2,
    px: 4,
    pb: 3,
};
```

}

```
const [updateOpen, setUpdateOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleUpdateOpen = () => setUpdateOpen(true);
const handleUpdateClose = () => setUpdateOpen(false);

<StyledModal
              aria-labelledby="unstyled-modal-title"
              aria-describedby="unstyled-modal-description"
              open={updateOpen}
              onClose={handleUpdateClose}
              BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
            >
              <Box sx={style(props)}>
                <h5>Enter password</h5>
                <form>
                  <DevicePasswordInput/>
                  <button className="blue-button" onClick={SendRequest}>GET RECORDS</button>
                </form>
                <br/>
              </Box>
        </StyledModal>
```

Hitting the ESC button on the keyboard does close the modal successfully. Running the handleUpdateClose() function successfully closes the modal also.

Stuck on this, I appreciate any help anyone can offer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but my code got out of date from the material ui docs...

This code:

```
BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
slots={{ backdrop: Backdrop }}
```